# Keyboard remapping with profiles

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping

So I am looking for a program that functions a lot like [XMBC](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) which is a program that allows you to remap / simulate key presses with your mouse buttons.

But I want to be able to remap key presses to allow for multiple presses with a single press, with a profiling system like XMBC that allows the program to have different mapping in different programs (not constant, linear mapping).

Any suggestions, because I cant find anything.
I know about AutoHotKey but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: If you have a Razer keyboard Synapse will do this

Comment: @jatuttle0 No sorry, just a laptop keyboard. But this is interesting thank you.